# Inaccessible Data after LUKS2 encryption

Tags: encryption, disk, luks

I tried to encrypt a HDD with an exisiting EXT4 partition on it using Luks2.
First I made room for the LUKS2 header (probably the issue I assume...):

```
resize2fs / dev/sdc1 2929710000
```

Then I started the encryption

```
cryptsetup reencrypt --encrypt --type luks2 --reduce-device.size 32m /dev/sdc1
```

Now I can open the device without any issues but I can't mount it and the output of gdisk looks like trouble:

```
root@esprimo:~# gdisk -l /dev/mapper/sdc-crypt
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.6

Warning: Partition table header claims that the size of partition table
entries is 3165299386 bytes, but this program  supports only 128-byte entries.
Adjusting accordingly, but partition table may be garbage.
Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v' to
verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to repair
the disk.
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: OK
Backup header: ERROR
Main partition table: OK
Backup partition table: ERROR

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
Disk /dev/mapper/sdc-crypt: 23437737983 sectors, 10.9 TiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): C8A0204A-192A-4437-A6C1-CD127AC8699A
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 23437770717
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048     23437770717   10.9 TiB    8300
```

Running w ind gdisk results in:

```
Caution! Secondary header was placed beyond the disk's limits! Moving the
header, but other problems may occur!

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
32768 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Problem: partition 1 is too big for the disk.
Aborting write operation!
Aborting write of new partition table.
```

Any hope I can recover my data?
Thansk so much fo any hints!